# Cannot profile XCTest in instruments

Tags: c++, xcode, xctest

I have a performance test in my XCTest group that I want to profile in Instruments. Now I right click on the test in the test navigator, hit `Profile "test..."` and Instruments launches.

When I choose the time profiler and hit record, the `xctest` target immediately exists with

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
<End of Run>
```

There is C++ code called from the `XCTestCase` method. I've manually linked `libc++/libstdc++/libc++abi.tbd` in the test target just to be sure, but with no success.

Why can't I profile this test?

Comment: Is this for unit or UI tests? If UI, it's possibly because Instruments is already occupied with running the test.

Comment: Unit tests of course. Nothing is running in Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

I observed something similar, in Xcode 9. However, I saw that after hitting `Profile "test..."`, if you choose a profile and then keep that instruments window open after the test quits, subsequent runs to `Profile "test..."` will hook into that window and it works fine.

There was no need to hit record, the profile runs immediately.